# Where should I set localStorage in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I try using redux and get started with Redux Toolkit. I was calling data by createAsyncThunk and got results, but I don't know where i can do handling localStorage.setItem. Should I handle it in Reducers or  another way?

Comment: You can set it in reducers, which that helps you to update the state as well

Comment: You should visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Answer (score 1):

Since setting and getting items from `localStorage` is kind of side effects, and middlewares like `redux-thunk` are used for performing side-effects, it is probably a good idea to do that in `createAsyncThunk` and not reducers:

for example:

```
        const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
      'users/fetchByIdStatus',
      async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
        const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId)
        // keep some data in localStorage
localStorage.setItem("lastVisit",JSON.stringify(response.data.lastVisit))
       
        // proceed to send data to reducers
        return response.data
      }
    )
```